# Form a newtork in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the table DDL and insert queries for sample data.

```
create table trxn_info
(
trxn_seq_id number,
client_name varchar2(4000),
grp_nm varchar2(4000)
);

insert into trxn_info (trxn_seq_id, client_name,grp_nm) values (1,'ankit',NULL);
insert into trxn_info (trxn_seq_id, client_name,grp_nm) values (2,'ankith',NULL);
insert into trxn_info (trxn_seq_id, client_name,grp_nm) values (3,'deepak',NULL);
insert into trxn_info (trxn_seq_id, client_name,grp_nm) values (4,'deepa',NULL);
insert into trxn_info (trxn_seq_id, client_name,grp_nm) values (5,'annkit',NULL);
```

**Problem statement:** Need SQL query to put clients into the one group where names are matching more than 80%. utl_match.edit_distance_similarity oracle utility is used for matching.

1.) "ankit, ankith and annkit" matches 80% with each other. G1 group will be assigned to these clients.

2.) "deepak and deepa" matches 80% with each other. G2 group will be assigned to these clients.

Below is the desired output:

[image]

Comment: I rather doubt that a single SQL query can do that. A block of PL/SQL code probably can.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller First preference is query. Even PL/SQL block will do.

Comment: UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY('ANKITH','ANNKIT') = 67 Refine your question rules.

Comment: The problem with this task is that different yet conflicting results can fulfill the requirements. For example, suppose you have "AxxxA", "AxxxB" and "BxxxB" (assuming this number of x allows for the requested 80% similarity if exactly one char differs).  AxxxB can be in a group with AxxxA and BxxxB, but AxxxA and BxxxB cannot be in the same group. So will you group AxxxB with AxxxA or with BxxxB?

Comment: The problem itself doesn't make sense. "Matching by 80% or more" is not a transitive relation, so those groups don't exist. Namely: name 1 and name 2 may match by 85%, name 2 and name 3 match by 85%, but name 1 and name 3 only match 70%. (One can very easily construct examples of this kind.) So, what groups do you create here?

Comment: @Serg yes you are correct. That was a miss from my end. you can keep the matching threshold to 67 to achieve result mentioned by me or assign the group as G3 to "annkit" client. Please try to give solution based on this approach

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller sorry I am not able to understand what are you trying to say. Can you explain with some other example?

Comment: @mathguy let me explain the functionality so that it will make sense for you. Here we are trying to do entity resolution using fuzzy match. so if my first client name matches with the second client's name by 80% business assumes both of them to be the same and a G1 group is assigned to them. if third client name matches 80% with first client name or second client name it will be assigned same group G1. Business does not want to match all previous client names in a group for any new client name.

Comment: You should be aware that "f third client name matches 80% with first client name or second client name" leads to a winner-takes-it-all situation where a few large groups will contain most of your clients. In my previous comment, as well as my answer, I assumed that each client must be similar to *all* other clients in the group, but now it seems that being similar to just *one* member of the group is enough. Therefore, whenever a group grows by accepting a new member, it will accept even more different new names, while the maximum distance between members of a group will also grow.

Answer (score 0):

This PL/SQL block goes through all record and assigns them to a group where they will match all existing members, or starts a new group if no such group exists yet.

Please remember that this will not necessarily create an optimal solution (with the least possible number of groups) but just a valid solution where no two distinct groups can be joined without violating the similarity condition. Finding an optimal solution is hard graph theory.

```
declare
  v_i number := 0;
  v_r trxn_info%rowtype;
begin
  loop
    begin
      select * into v_r from trxn_info where grp_nm is null and rownum=1;
    exception
      when no_data_found then exit;
    end;

    begin
      select grp_nm into v_r.grp_nm from (
        select grp_nm from trxn_info
          where grp_nm is not null
          group by grp_nm
          having 80<=min(UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY(client_name,v_r.client_name))
      ) where rownum=1;
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        v_i := v_i+1;
        v_r.grp_nm := 'G'||v_i;
    end;
    update trxn_info set grp_nm = v_r.grp_nm where trxn_seq_id = v_r.trxn_seq_id;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Fiddle hier: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=45dfe271b8ebf909bd97aea3f2edb64c

Comment: Replace `80<=min` with `80<=max` to make each client join a group where they are similar with *at least one* other client.